# How do I backup/restore fzf.vim recentfile history?

Tags: fzf

A very simple question, where is the data stored related to fzf.vim?

I'd like to copy my "fzf recent file history" from one machine to another... Can't seem to find this mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be using the 'oldfiles' in vim where it's location can be determined by the following answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17260/13656

In my case it's `~/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada`.